# Sharing single POSTGRESQL connection between several method of same class

Tags: python, postgresql, class, methods, singleton

I have this brick-wall, I am trying to overcome. However, I am taking this route (single connection sharing ) because the previous approach (multiple connection) failed me when I had to access a particular table with different connection object from another method. So basically, with singleton connection approach, see sample code below;

```
import sys, psycopg2


class myclass():
   def __inti__(self):
      pass

# Declaring DB connection

def dbconn(self):
    try:
        connect_string = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='',    user='',password='')
        self.con = connect_string.cursor()
    except:
        print('Connection Error')

    # return dbconn
    print(self.con, 'this is at dbconn method level')
    return self.con


def registration(self):
    """ Detail of our Contacts is being collected"""

    print('Enter 1 or 2 to update Network Provider)
    update_data = int(input('Enter your 1 or 2 :'))
    if update_data == 1:
        network_name = input('Enter name of the Network Provider : ')
        # Calling db_conn method in order to established connection to DB SERVER
        try:
            local_con = myclass().dbconn()
            print(local_con, 'this is at registration method level')

        except:
            if local_con:
                local_con.rollback()

            print('Error  Connection')

        # Sending the data to the database for permanent storage

        local_con.execute(
            "INSERT INTO network(network_name)VALUES(%s)", (network_name,))
        local_con.commit()
        print('Data Save properly')
```

**The above code resulted into this output from my console,**

```
You can update Network Provider, API Setting and Price here
Enter 1 or 2 to update Network Provider
Enter your 1 or 2 :1
Enter name of the Network Provider : starcom Nigeria
<cursor object at 0x0000000002FD7EA0; closed: 0> this is at dbconn method level
<cursor object at 0x0000000002FD7EA0; closed: 0> this is at registration method level
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/myswitch.py", line 258, in <module>
new_provider.registration()
File "/myswitch.py", line 53, in registration
local_con.commit()
AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute   'commit'
```

from the above output, I understand that i can access (self.con) from dbconn() method in another method registration() of same class, however, the commit() attribute which i expected on the local variable under registration() failed with following code
     AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute   'commit'

Hence, transaction failed to save to the DB.
Hope I can lead on how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: **def __inti__** ?

Comment: Please read about Classes and OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've assigned your "self.con = connect_string.cursor()" and therefore local_con to a cursor? The commit needs to come from the psycopg2.connect class.

So it needs to be connect_string.commit() in your case.